# Odd "map 100% reduce 0%@ output in Hadoop Java job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In my job's output I've got a `...Job: map 100% reduce 0%` line printed for every expected `...Job: map n% reduce -%` line printed in my output. Other than this, the job runs as expected.

See line 6, 22 and 28 below (prefixed with stars). Any ideas why that happens, or what it means?

```
14/03/12 14:51:56 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
14/03/12 14:51:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/03/12 14:51:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
14/03/12 14:51:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 51192402; bufvoid = 104857600
14/03/12 14:51:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 18693168(74772672); length = 7521229/6553600
** 14/03/12 14:51:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 25% reduce 0%
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > sort
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1547766427_0001_m_000007_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1547766427_0001_m_000007_0' done.
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1547766427_0001_m_000007_0
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1547766427_0001_m_000008_0
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://<removed>.lzo:0+21976289
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
14/03/12 14:51:59 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
** 14/03/12 14:52:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/03/12 14:52:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
14/03/12 14:52:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/03/12 14:52:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
14/03/12 14:52:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 52931779; bufvoid = 104857600
14/03/12 14:52:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 18670736(74682944); length = 7543661/6553600
** 14/03/12 14:52:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 29% reduce 0%
```

**edit:**

I still don't know exactly why this happens, but I was running in local mode by mistake. Running the job in cluster mode (is that what it's called), displays the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have reducers.
Did you verify on the jobTracker localhost?

Comment: What makes you believe there are no reducers?

Comment: because if I understood well, you always have 0% reduce, which looks like when setting the number of reduce tasks to Zero

Comment: Ah, I see. No, the "problem" (the job finished normally), is that the output is e.g. Map 0% Reduce 0% -> Map 33% Reduce 0% -> Map 100% Reduce 0% -> Map 66% Reduce 0% -> Map 100% Reduce 0% -> Map 99% Reduce 0% -> Map 100% Reduce 0% -> Map 100% Reduce 0% -> Map 100% Reduce 50% -> Map 100% Reduce 100% -> DONE

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using old API;
saying by looking at "org.apache.hadoop.mapred", try "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce" instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, not a single mapred import in sight. I'll try and create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.